# Sort through array of n-dimensional objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort through arrays of n-dimensional objects based on a certain index. For example if I have an array:

```
var array1 = [['c',24,"John"],['a',-13,"Cindy"],['b',98,"Alex"]];
```

I want to be able to sort by any dimension. Does anything exist in javascript that would give me outputs that look like the following?

```
array1.sort(sortFunction(0));
- [['a',-13,"Cindy"],['b',98,"Alex"],['c',24,"John"]]

array1.sort(sortFunction(1));
- [['a',-13,"Cindy"],['c',24,"John"],['b',98,"Alex"]]

array1.sort(sortFunction(2));
- [['b',98,"Alex"],['a',-13,"Cindy"],['c',24,"John"]]
```

Thanks!

To clarify: I am aware you must write a sort function, but can you write one that takes in an argument? Here would be an example:

```
function sortFunction(dim){
  if (a[dim] === b[dim]) {
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    return (a[dim] < b[dim]) ? -1 : 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no built-in feature like the `sortFunction()` you've postulated, but you can write one yourself of course.

Comment: Your sort function needs to compare two properties of the elements (or the two elements) themselves. It needs to return a negative number if they are in the correct order, `0` if they are equivalent and a positive number if they are in the wrong order.

Comment: You say "n-dimensional", but your example is "two-dimensional". Do you want a solution for the two-dimensional case?

Comment: I am aware you have to write a sort function that compares two elements but can you send it arguments? And yes sorry, the answer does not need to work for n-dimensional arrays but for the arrays (or ideally objects) of any length contained within the array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a function generator that take the index of the parameters in your array :

```
var array = [['a',24,"John"],['a',-13,"Cindy"],['b',98,"Alex"]];

  function sorting(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        return a[index] < b[index]?-1:(a[index] > b[index])?1:0;
    }
  }

  var res1 = array.sort(sorting(0));
  var res2 = array.sort(sorting(1));
  var res3 = array.sort(sorting(2));
```

Comment: Actually, this solution is even better than mine, because you can reuse the function code even more efficiently. Just like [georg’s deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31839490/4642212)…

Comment: Using closure for that simple problem isn't wise, OP really didn't understand the thing going on IMHO

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** this is the basic approach of how the `sort` callback function works. For a more elegant solution see [Paul Boute’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31839186/sort-through-array-of-n-dimensional-objects-in-javascript/31839427#31839427). His solution is especially useful when the function needs to be applied in more than one situation.

---

Your sort function needs to compare two properties of the elements (or the two elements) themselves. It needs to return a negative number if they are in the correct order, `0` if they are equivalent and a positive number if they are in the wrong order.

A JavaScript example of such a function:

```
function sortFunction(elementA,elementB,index){
  if(elementA[index]<elementB[index]){
    return -1;
  }
  else if(elementA[index]>elementB[index]){
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Invokable as such:

```
array1.sort(function(a,b){
  return sortFunction(a,b,1);
});
```

---

Or the shorter all-in-one version:

```
array1.sort(function(a,b){
  var index=1;
  if(a[index]<b[index]){
    return -1;
  }
  else if(a[index]>b[index]){
    return 1;
  }
  else{
    return 0;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a library like `underscore.js`. Then, simply

```
// which index to sort on
var s = 1;
// sort it - it will work for objects too
_.sortBy(array1, function(a){ return a[s];});

// or simply use "property name" to sort on
_.sortBy( array1, s);
```